# Which Stack Exchange site is for suggestions on improving one's study of mathematics?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Someone kindly direct me to a Stack Exchange where I could properly pose questions about improving my study and reading of mathematics.  I may be suffering from limitations of talent, but I notice often I am stumped by exercises because I do not read them with sufficient care.   When I have spent an inordinate amount of time going down the wrong paths, I frequently see that I have been careless, not having taken the time to understand: I have passed over something too quickly in my haste to solve the problem. It may be an incurable fault, I know, but perhaps discussing it would help me.

Comment: Questions about personal help aren't really a good fit for our network.

Comment: At least, I did not lose much time at Meta.

Comment: It looks like you've found the solution to your problem already.

Comment: Q&A is not for discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematics Stack Exchange has a [[learning] tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) for

> Questions about the process of learning mathematics, both inside and outside a formal environment, including learning strategies, recommendations for learning particular subjects, and studying habits.

But I fear it's going to be hard to state your question in a way that's 1) objective 2) detailed enough and 3) useful to future visitors. Perhaps the users on [Mathematics' own Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) can help?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent your request involves learning on your own, note that Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange's [[self-learning] tag](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning) is for

> Questions about how someone learns on their his or her own, outside of traditional classroom environments.

I suggest you go through at least some of the questions listed there (currently 126 of them). You may find at least one or two which help you with your current situation. Also, if you wish to ask a question there, doing a check of a few of these questions first will give you a better idea of how suitable your question would be. Nonetheless, I recommend before posting that you also first carefully read at least the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages linked from their [Help Center](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help) page.